# How to get httpd -S running in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2

I have /etc/apache2 and i included my Fedora httpd.conf virtual host files and wanted to check the details. But i get this. How to get it working?

```
# httpd -S
No command 'httpd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dhttpd' from package 'dhttpd' (universe)
 Command 'xttpd' from package 'xtide' (universe)
 Command 'thttpd' from package 'thttpd' (universe)
httpd: command not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apache controlling script on Ubuntu is `apachectl`, just use:

```
apachectl -S
```

Answer (score 0):

on Ubutu you can do

```
apache2 -S
```